# windows program "webroot" blocks access to tor download

Tags: windows, help, website

just sent a friend to https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en

she has something called webroot installed, and this is the error message;

Suspicious attack ahead

Webroot has blocked access to the website you tried to open.
It has been reported to contain suspicious content.

not sure what to tell her

Comment: If the issue is just fetching a copy of tor, then they can use one of the methods outlined on [GetTor](https://gettor.torproject.org/) but webroot is already hooking and interfering with TLS connections inside the browser so they might be better off using [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) to get rid of the webroot spyware entirely if they actually need privacy or anonymity while browsing.

Comment: Thank you.

I passed along your response, and the response from last year

Answer (score 2):

There is a [thread on the Webroot forums about this](https://community.webroot.com/t5/Webroot-SecureAnywhere-Antivirus/Why-does-Webroot-dislike-Tor-browser-and-will-not-allow-download/td-p/231277), and here's an official answer from December 2015:

> Hello everyone,
>
> I just got off the phone with one of our team members that handles this and apparently torproject.org is classified as a 10 in our system as opposed to an 81 which is what I saw. The reason for this is because it is considered a proxy, and many large employers would not like employees navigating to this site.
>
> There is quite a bit of back and forth on our end in regards to this and it may change in the future(hopefully) Smiley Wink
>
> In regards to Tor itself, that is a safe website to navigate to and if you want to continue to it, when the block comes up simply click "Tell me more about it" and then click "Unblock page and continue." This should create an override on your machine and while the search results will still show the red annotations, the site should no longer get blocked upon navigation.
>
> I will update this thread once I know more or if we make a change to this.
>
> Regards,
>   James G.
>
> Online Retention Specialist